# Estimating death based on repeating sequence?

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model

Currently I'm working on a project, and I reading up on Survival Regression with Cox’s proportional hazard model, which looks like it will work to answer the questions I want to ask.

My issue is that my data is not in the duration / event form, and I'm not sure how to convert it into this form.

For simplicity sake let's say I'm recording repeat customers who visit my shop, now I know two things about them, I know when visit and I know when they don't. They haven't "signed up" to be my customers and when they stop shopping with me they don't "unsubscribe", and I want to create a metric that determines the likelyhood that a customer will continue to shop with me.

How can I determine a "death" event without a death event, do I factor in an average shopping interval? If they don't return within their standard deviation I count them as "dead?" If someone has shopped within a month do I automatically count them as alive and right-censor them?

Comment: I would approach this question by considering the costs and benefits.  What benefit do you get from recording a customer as "dead" and what would it cost you when you record a customer as dead but they are not?  If neither amount really matters, then the answer doesn't matter either; otherwise, this will be essential information for determining a good procedure.

Comment: Recommend studying this Q&A: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/285288/241093.  It seems more appropriate to model time until next return with a recurrent events model, rather than time to "not returning".

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. After giving it some thought I'm consider that perhaps I need to decide on a delimeter, say at least 3 months, and if a person hasn't visited within that time I create a new record for them. Breaking up all my previous data by that delimeter, then my model should in theory predict the probability of a "gap" coming, of at least 3 months. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: You should @ who you are responding to, so they get a notification.  And I am not clear on what you are thinking.  It sounds like you are only planning to have observations with 3+-month gaps, so how can you model probability of that gap coming when all your observations have the same outcome value?  You should probably update the question (by editing it) with an example of the data structure (dependent and independent variables) you are considering setting up.